# Unable to scrape a website with styled-component javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, scrapy, styled-components

#### My goal

Get basic informations from this [page](https://www.compass.com/listing/12-14-31st-avenue-unit-2-queens-ny-11106/642578007460313273/) with using Scrapy framework, but question is no specific to this framework. Let's take the `p` element inside the `h1` node for exemple.

#### Issue

All the selections I make with the response I get from my Scrapy requests are failing to return what's inside the `h1` node.

```sh
scrapy shell 'url'
response
>>> 200
response.xpath('//h1/p')
>>> []
```

**Fetching the response:**

When fetching the response, I see a structure i can't really understand with all the main html markup condensed and placed just after a bunch of javascript styled-components. The [file is here](https://gist.github.com/AxZxP/2aaaa84134dba47241493cd4b1c1c72c#file-response-html-L1725) (ligne 1725).

#### My process

**Testing the selector from dev-tool:**

*After disabling Javascript* from the dev tools and testing my selector, I get the desired result. For exemple I get the `<p>` element inside the `<h1>` with a simple query `//h1/p` from the console.

**testing the selector with scrapy shell:**

Not working, see Issue

**testing the selector with splash:**

I get the exact same result as shown in the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the error, but I can hopefull provide an answer to your problem

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="summary__StyledAddress-e4c4ok-6 zWwUF textIntent-title1"]/text()').get()
```

returns : '12-14 31st Avenue, Unit 2 '

Which is hopefully what you need?

Dr P.

Comment: I tried a lot of techniques including Selenium and Splash and none succeed to return a structured html markup. Only your solution of refining xpath selectors without referencing parents nodes is working.